# Oracle SQL: Trying to search values containing number but exclude some of the records

Tags: sql, oracle

Have a table containing address details with Cities for which some contain numbers that indicate the City district:

| ID | CITY | COUNTRY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Praha 4 | CZE |
| 2 | Dublin 1 | GBR |
| 3 | Budapest 3 | HUN |
| 4 | Dublin | GBR |
| 5 | Praha 7 | CZE |
| 6 | Budapest | HUN |

Would like to extract all Cities that contain numbers but excluding Praha.

Tried a combination of WHERE with LIKE and NOT LIKE or != as well as subquery excluding Praha or entire Country 'CZE' but always end up with all the values containing numbers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(city, '\s+\d+$')
AND    city NOT LIKE 'Praha%'
```

Or, from Oracle 12, without (slow) regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_NUMBER(
         SUBSTR(city, INSTR(city, ' ', -1))
         DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR
       ) IS NOT NULL
AND    city NOT LIKE 'Praha%'
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, CITY, COUNTRY) AS
SELECT 1, 'Praha 4',    'CZE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Dublin 1',   'GBR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Budapest 3', 'HUN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Dublin',     'GBR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Praha 7',    'CZE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Budapest',   'HUN' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | CITY | COUNTRY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | Dublin 1 | GBR |
> | 3 | Budapest 3 | HUN |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=44b7206e0023b65e21233207eb452b37)*